# what's wrong in my URL validation Regex using jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

I have this validate function :

```
function validate_url(url)
    {
        var pattern1= new RegExp(/^((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)$/);
        var pattern2= new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[.][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*([.][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)*$/);
        if (pattern1.test(url) || pattern2.test(url))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and I want to check url validation for these patterns :

```
     * www.example.com
     * http://www.example.com
     * http://example.com
     * http://example.example.com
     * https://www.example.com
     * https://example.com
     * https://example.example.com
     * example.example.com
     * example.com
```

".com" is optional .

Actually , it was working until I test this url :

```
      www,google.com
```

It accepts the comma !! 
I tried to remove it from my regular expression and it still accept it !
what's wrong with it ?
I made a big search for a suitable regular expression for my case but they were so HUGE and didn't give me what I want .
any suggestion ?
Thanks in advance