# javascript url check and repair

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am allowing my users to insert a website url.

As you all know, some people are completely useless, typing whatever to the input, without any check.

I want to do a test on the user inputted url, to check if it is valid, and if not, repair it automatically using javascript, before displaying it to the public.

Example user submitted urls:

- http://google.com
- www.google.com
- google.com
- http//google.com
- htp:/google.com
- ++++++++

---

```
var web = user.url;

var urlCheck = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

if(web){
    if(urlCheck.test(web) === false) {
        web = "http://" + web;
    }

    $('div.Link').html("<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"externalLink('" + web + "');\">" + web + "</a>");
}
```

Suggestions on for an even better check/test to avoid problems?

Comment: Oh the irony. Mentions users "typing whatever to the input, without any check.", doesn't even check that his own question formats correctly ;) (yeah, someone else fixed it)

Comment: haha... there you go, my question is absolutely valid :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function is_valid_url(url)
{
     return url.match(/^(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/);
}
```

Call the `is_valid_url(YOUR_WEBSITE_URL)` function anywhere you want URL validation and it will return true or false

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364997/2482430)